# jQuery tablesorter with number_format();

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, number-formatting

I'm using the jQuery tablesorter plugin and I'd like to make my table more readable by using a comma delimiter on the thousands, i.e. number_format($value, 0, " ", ",");

However, this disrupts the sorting. I've been searching for a solution (e.g. http://lab.christianmontoya.com/jquery-tablesort-numbers-commas/), but I haven't managed to adjust it and accommodate my table. I'm new to scripting, so please be indulgent.

What should my javascript block look like?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( {
            sortList: [[1,1], [2,1]],
            widgets: ['zebra'],
        } );
    }); 
</script>
</head>


<body>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
<th>Username</th> 
<th>Level</th> 
<th>Experience</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
<td>Fiery</td> 
<td><?php echo number_format(2400, 0, " ", ","); ?></td> 
<td><?php echo number_format(378433689, 0, " ", ",");?></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td>Sixten</td> 
<td><?php echo number_format(1600, 0, " ", ","); ?></td> 
<td><?php echo number_format(1000000000, 0, " ", ",");?></td> 
</tr> 
<tr>                    
<td>Penny</td> 
<td><?php echo number_format(885, 0, " ", ","); ?></td> 
<td><?php echo number_format(8900002, 0, " ", ","); ?></td> 
</tr> 
<tr>
<td>Petra</td> 
<td><?php echo number_format(2400, 0, " ", ","); ?></td> 
<td><?php echo number_format(398433889, 0, " ", ","); ?></td> 
</tr> 
<tr>
<td>Neu</td> 
<td><?php echo number_format(4974, 0, " ", ","); ?></td> 
<td><?php echo number_format(198433889, 0, " ", ","); ?></td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to apply your custom format to the header/column you want:

Markup:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Price
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    1,000.00
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    100,100.00
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    100,980.00
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    100,122.00
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    120,122.00
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    540,122.00
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    222,122.00
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    100,020.00
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    100,251.00
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    100,364.00
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    300,122.00
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.tablesorter.addParser({
            id: "fancyNumber",
            is: function (s) {
                return /^[0-9]?[0-9,\.]*$/.test(s);
            },
            format: function (s) {
                return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(/,/g, ''));
            },
            type: "numeric"
        });

        $("#myTable").tablesorter({
            headers: { 0: { sorter: 'fancyNumber'} },
            widgets: ['zebra']
        });
    });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eAgDC/

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. One issue still remains, though. It sorts the numbers by the first delimiter, e.g. 1,000,000,000 as 1, whereas in my table it is meant to be a billion. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You've got to show me what you mean. Please create a jsFiddle so that I can see it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to show you what I mean in code. I don't want the comma delimiter(s) to have any impact on the evaluation of the number. E.g. I want "2,400" to be valued (and sorted) as "2400" (as if there was no delimiter). Right now 2,400 gets sorted as "2,4". Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I understand what you mean. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: I have tested several numbers and it works just fine. Did you try the example on the jsFiddle? It does not treat 2,400 as 2,4 but as 2400 (You can even try to add 2400 with no comma and still works, in fact that is what the replace function is doing, getting rid of the commas and evaluating it as a whole.)

Comment: You're right! I'm sorry, I forgot to change this line:
headers: { 0: { sorter: 'fancyNumber'} },  to accommodate my table. How do I add multiple headers? I want it to apply to headers 1 and 2.

Comment: Add another column to the header filter (look how I add the first column): http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html